# Ruby - slice array and copy date values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Pretty new to Ruby, I am having trouble implementing some logic
I have a lot of dates (effective and expiration dates).
I also have 2 objects. An original object, and a new copied object (it is a copy of the original)

I want to loop through each pair of dates, and check the orignal objects dates fields to see if ti had any.  If it did have dates, then I was to:

- use the original objects expiration date as the new objects effective date
- default the new objects expiration date to the new effective date + 1 year

Here is my code, I get this error:

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

CODE:

```
 DATE_FIELDS = [:agency_effective_on, :agency_expire_on,
                        :field_effective_on, :field_expire_on,
                        :product_manager_effective_on, :product_manager_expire_on,
                        :officer_effective_on, :officer_expire_on,
                        :regional_officer_effective_on, :regional_officer_expire_on]

    @copy_to = @copy_from.dup

     DATE_FIELDS.each.slice(2) do |field|
              if !@copy_from.send(field[0].to_sym).nil? #if the ORIGNAL date is not nil
                #copy it to the new Objects dates
                @copy_to.send("#{field[0]}=".to_sym, @copy_from.send(field[0]))
                @copy_to.send("#{field[1]}=".to_sym, @copy_from.send(field[1]).to_date + 365)
              end
            end
```

Comment: Is your code valid ? This code seems invalid:
`DATE_FIELDS.each.slice(2) do |field|`

Comment: Is that invalid have I made a mistake there?

Comment: It should be each_slice I think,  I'll have to correct that and work on my logic..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I had `each.slice` instead of `each_slice`